# Cancel current synchronous request processing

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, webforms, task-parallel-library

I am trying to cancel current request made by user. Web Forms Web App have export to excel feature. If it takes long time to generate excel report user can cancel the request.

Once the cancel button is clicked the server should stop processing to save precious bandwidth.

I have found two solutions as listed below.

**First Solution:**

Prevent further code from executing by jumping straight to the `Application_EndRequest` event.

```
    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Response.IsClientConnected)
        {

            HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();

        }


    }
```

**Second Solution:** (Using Task Parallel Library - TPL)

```
   CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }


    protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CancellationToken cToken = tokenSource.Token;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
                // do some heavy work here

                GenerateReport(sender, cToken);

                if (cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {

                // another thread decided to cancel
                  return;

                }

        }, cToken);

        // to register a delegate for a callback when a
        // cancellation request is made

        cToken.Register(() => cancelNotification());

    }

    private void GenerateReport(object sender, CancellationToken ct)
    {

    var students = _context.Students.ToList();

    var courses = _context.Courses.ToList();

    var teachers = _context.Teachers.ToList();

    // Todo: Use above data to Generate Excel Report

    // Just to Simulate Export to excel

        Thread.Sleep(7000);

    }


    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            tokenSource.Cancel();

    }


    private static void cancelNotification()
    {
        // Why never called ?

    }
```

In second solution I have used [Task Parallel Library (TPL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-based-asynchronous-programming)  and registered a callback method on cancellation using `CancellationToken`. I have few questions:

1. But the callback  method is never called when I click cancel button, may I know why ?
2. Using `Entity framework` can I cancel all 3 `.ToList()` statements before it hits the database to fetch the data.
3. Also may I know is it best option to go with `TPL` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2012/06/06/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/

Comment: @GertArnold , But still my Registered `cancelNotification()` method is not called when the Task is cancelled. ?

Comment: This whole `cancelNotification()` becomes irrelevant if you upgrade your code to proper `async-await` syntax. That's what the link suggests.

Comment: @GertArnold , Ok if i use `async-await` How to make sure the task is cancelled , is there a property ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to register the callbackfunction befor you start the Task. Your Code have to look something like this.

In you Page_Load method you have to save the CancellationTokenSource in the User session.

```
public partial class Contact : Page
{
    CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] != null)
        {
            tokenSource = HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] as CancellationTokenSource;
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("Cart", new CancellationTokenSource());
            tokenSource = HttpContext.Current.Session["Cart"] as CancellationTokenSource;
        }
    }


    protected void btnExportExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CancellationToken cToken = tokenSource.Token;
        cToken.Register(() => cancelNotification());

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
        // do some heavy work here

        GenerateReport(sender, cToken);

            if (cToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {

            // another thread decided to cancel
            return;

            }

        }, cToken);
    }

    private void GenerateReport(object sender, CancellationToken ct)
    {

        var students = _context.Students.ToList();

        var courses = _context.Courses.ToList();

        var teachers = _context.Teachers.ToList();

        // Todo: Use above data to Generate Excel Report

        // Just to Simulate Export to excel

        Thread.Sleep(7000);

    }


    protected void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tokenSource.Cancel();

    }


    private static void cancelNotification()
    {
        // Why never called ?

    }
}
```

Your second question.

You can load the list async. With the Method `ToListAsync()` and there you can give your canalactiontoken in it.

[Microsoft Dokumentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dn220262(v=vs.113).aspx)

I hope this help you?

Comment: But still `cancelNotification()` method is not called when the Task is cancelled.

Comment: Thanks for letting know `.ToListAsync()` but lets say we have 3 `.ToListAsync()` calls. And 1st call hits the database and is in process to fetch data , at the same time can I cancel and prevent 2nd and 3rd to not to hit the database ?

Comment: @stom I update my solution. The problem for the first problem is that you need to store the token in the user session.

Comment: @stom when you call to ListAsync() all 3 database request wil work parallel (in the same time) so if you cancel the token all 3 will stop to recieve data from database connection. The problem is, that the User have always the posibility to canncel the work you always have the problem, that your database request the statment and the user press the canncel button.

Comment: @stom and for your last question. I have no anwser because I have not that much experience personaly I do most of my code with the TPL. But that only my personal opinion. Sorry that I cant help you in this point.

Comment: Still it doesn't call `cancelNotification()` method. Ok you said `all 3 database request wil work parallel`. Are you sure ? How come ? because `.ListAsync()` is 3 separate statements ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174927/discussion-between-darem-and-stom).